# Get array size in oracle sql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I have a table in oracle with this definition

```
    create table PARAM(
       ID VARCHAR(30),
       DOCUMENT   blob
    )
```

`Document` is stored in a json format.

```
{"id":"value","parameters":[{...},{...},{...}]}
```

How can i extract size for array parameters in sql?

I need extract array size for each table record, and after sum all this values.

ex:

1 step:

```
    ID    ARRAY_SIZE
    ----  ----------
    1     10
    2     0
    3     3
```

2 step:

```
    TOTAL_RECORDS   TOTAL_ARRAYS_SIZE
    -------------   -----------------
    3               13
```

Can someone please give me an idea how to do that ?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have an `is json` check constraint on the column, you can use the `size()` method to get the number elements in an array:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, 
  c2 varchar2(100) 
    check ( c2 is json ) 
);

insert into t values ( 1, '{ "arr" : [1, 2, 3] }');
insert into t values ( 2, '{ "arr" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }');

select c1, t.c2.arr.size() from t t;

C1    T.C2.ARR.SIZE()   
 1                  3 
 2                  5
```

Comment: What version of Oracle does this work on? [Oracle 18 db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5189d31e27da1e5753299a256f4f094) does not work.

Comment: [18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-8656CAB9-C293-4A99-BB62-F38F3CFC4C13); you can use it with `json_value ( c2, '$.arr.size()' )`. Not sure what the issue with dot-notation is

Answer (score 0):

For case with a `blob` field I see the following decision.

You have a table something like this

```
create table tmp_js
(
   id       number,
   document blob  
);
```

And table with json objects looks like this

```
ID    Document 
----  ----------
1     {"id": 1, "paramters": [{"t": 2}, {"t": 3}]}
2     {"id": 2, "paramters": [{"t": 2}, {"t": 3}, {"t": 4}]}
3     {"id": 3, "paramters": [{"t": 2}, {"t": 3}, {"t": 5}, {"t": 6}]}
```

Then you can resolve your task by following way

**Step 1**

You will get row's id and size of array in row's document.

```
select
    t.id,            
    (select
        count(*)
    from
        json_table(json_query(t.document, '$.paramters'), '$[*]' columns (value path '$.t'))
    ) as cnt       
from
    tmp_js t
```

**Step2**

You can make total summary from result of first step.

```
select
    count(*),
    sum(cnt)
from    
    (select
        t.id,            
        (select
            count(*)
        from
            json_table
            (
                json_query(t.document, '$.paramters'), 
                '$[*]' columns (value path '$.t')
            )
        ) as cnt       
    from
        tmp_js t)
```